# Bug with sp_execute_external_script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, r

I think I encountered a bug with [sp_execute_external_script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt604368.aspx), so here is the replay.

I will get an error if I run the following script:

```
-- error occurs
exec sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R'
, @script = N' result <- as.data.frame(c(i, j));'
, @params = N'@i varchar(100), @j varchar(100)'
, @i = 'hello'
, @j = 'world'
, @output_data_1_name = N'result' -- the position of this param caused problem
with result sets ((test varchar(100)));
```

I will get an error

> Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Procedure or function  has too many arguments specified.

However, if I just move up the `@output_data_1_name` like the following:

```
-- NO error occurs
exec sp_execute_external_script @language=N'R'
, @script = N' result <- as.data.frame(c(i, j));'
, @output_data_1_name = N'result' -- this position in front of @parms caused NO problem
, @params = N'@i varchar(100), @j varchar(100)'
, @i = 'hello'
, @j = 'world'
with result sets ((test varchar(100)));
```

I will get a normal output:

[image]

Does anyone know whether I am doing something wrong or it indeed could be a bug in SQL Server 2016?

My environment is (by `select @@version`):

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU1) (KB3208177) - 13.0.4411.0 (X64) 
    Jan  6 2017 14:24:37 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )
```

**Update**:
I tested a little bit more and indeed the position of parameters will cause errors, such as following:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script 
 @script = N' result <- as.data.frame(c(i, j));'
, @output_data_1_name = N'result' -- the position of this param caused NO problem
, @params = N'@i varchar(100), @j varchar(100)'
, @i = N'hello'
, @j = N'world'
, @language=N'R' -- if I put @language here, it will cause error
with result sets ((test varchar(100)));
```

or this:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script  @language=N'R'
, @script = N' result <- as.data.frame(c(i, j));'
, @output_data_1_name = N'result' -- the position of this param caused NO problem
, @i = N'hello'
, @j = N'world'
, @params = N'@i varchar(100), @j varchar(100)'
with result sets ((test varchar(100)));
```

The error message will be:

> Msg 214, Level 16, State 175, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 19]
>   Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

But I actually give each parameter of type `nvarchar` already.

I will consider open a bug report to MS if I do not see anyone pointing out my "errors".

Comment: AFAIK sp_execute_external_script is a CLR function, I suppose that params represents a variable number of arguments, then it should be place at end of the param list.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter list in `@params` can have names matching the names of the parameters used by the `sp_execute_external_script` procedure itself, like `@script` or `@language`, for instance. There would need to be a way, then, to determine whether a parameter pertains to the system SP or to the user script.

Making it a rule that `@params` be always specified last in the list of the parameters pertaining to `sp_execute_external_script` and all the parameters specified after `@params` be considered pertaining to the user script is one easy way to implement the distinction. So, if a parameter like `@language` is specified after `@params`, it will be interpreted as a script parameter and not the SP's parameter.

And I believe that is what is happening in the cases where you are specifying `@output_data_1_name` or `@language` after `@params`. Those parameters simply must go before `@params` to avoid potential ambiguity.

Granted, there is not a word about this [in the manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt604368.aspx), which, however, is a problem with the manual more than a problem with `sp_execute_external_script`.

Comment: Thanks Anndriy, I vote your theory up since it works, i.e. anything after @ params are considered part of @ params. But I am not sure it is a bug in the document or it is a bug in the SP itself. Could any CLR expert here explains whether in such business requirement, there is NO way to put the parameters of a CLR SP arbitrarily or we have to follow a specified order of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I received the following reply from MS Connect, I purposely highlight the key info (in bold font).
So in short, it is indeed a by-design behavior. :-)

> Greetings from Microsoft Connect!
>
> This notification was generated for feedback item:
>   sp_execute_external_script will report error when named parameters are
>   not in a specific position. which you submitted at theMicrosoft
>   Connect site.
>
> **This behavior is by design. The mandatory parameters like @language,
>   @script have to be specified first before the user-defined parameters.
>   This is like sp_executesql behavior in T-SQL today.**
>
> You may receive a general "Feedback Item Updated" notification as
>   well, if any other changes were made by Microsoft.
>
> Thank you for using Microsoft Connect!
>
> Regards,
>
> the Microsoft Connect Team